# How to retrieve multiple data in one column field in db and show it each by each into input field

Tags: java, html, mysql, spring-mvc

I want to saved a 2 input field with the same path.
   I want to display a data, I have two input fields with the same path. But unfortunately when i click update it shows in each field the two inputted values separated by comma. EX values are in each input field. 6,9 but i want to see when client updates into 
    6
    9
    like for example what does the client inputs on first field must be same when client wants to update as well as in second field. Can someone help me?

```
<div class="form-group">
<label class="control-label col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-12"></label>
<div class="col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-12">
  <form:input path="description3" id="and1" type="text"/>
</div>
  </div>
<div class="form-group">
   <label class="control-label col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-12"></label>
  <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-12">
         <form:input path="description3" id="and2" type="text"/>
  </div>
</div>


I expecting that the result is like if what you input on first field and second field , and when you click update must show what value does first field and second field has.
```

But it shows the first field was showing 15,16
   And also the second field shows 15,16
    So i want is like this ex.

```
first field i inputted
15
second field i inputted
16
```

the error is like first and second field shows 15,16
   i want to see
   15
    16

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood, the task is to print out the values user entered.

If so, you need to somehow access those values in your controller.

That is where the 'command object' comes in handy.

You basically create a java representation of your inputs, let's say input1 and input2. If so, your command object should look like this:

```
public class CommandObject {
    private String input1;
    private String input2;

    //getter, setters
}
```

In your controller create a method that responds to a GET method, sets the command object and returns a form:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String formGet(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("commandObject", new CommandObject()); 
    // this object is available in your view
    return "form";
}
```

Then create a form:

```
<spring:url value="/" var="formUrl" />
<form:form action="${formUrl}" method="post"
    modelAttribute="commandObject">
    <br>
    <form:input path="input1" id="input1" /> 
    <%-- after submitting the form the value from this input will be stored in 
    commandObject.input1 --%>

    <br>

    <form:input path="input2" id="input2" />
    <%-- after submitting the form the value from this input will be stored in 
    commandObject.input2 --%>
    <br>

    <button type="submit">Submit</button>

</form:form>
```

Then create a method that will respond to a POST request:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String formPost(@ModelAttribute CommandObject commandObject) {
    System.out.println(commandObject.getInput1() + " " + commandObject.getInput2());
    return "home";
}
```

Here you basically get the form data with @ModelAttribute and print out the needed values.

That's about it!

I highly recommend you check to official documentation about this matter:

https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-ann-modelattrib-method-args

https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-ann-modelattrib-methods